# GNOME - Chrome contextual menu colors inconsistent with current theme

Tags: gnome, themes, google-chrome

I've put together an icon/theme combination for my Ubuntu 14.04 + GNOME. 
Unfortunately, my color settings for contextual menu are applied for most applications, but not for Chrome - when I right-click on a website in Chrome, the menu that shows up has different highlight and background colors than what I've designed (the ones that do show up are quite ugly!). The contextual menu in Nautilus looks fine, though.

How do I fix that? Is there a separate set of styles for other kinds of contextual menus?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I've figured it out. Some applications use GTK2, and I've been only styling GTK3. My bad

Comment: Another wrinkle is that [Chrome is now using Aura](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/207zr3/google_to_replace_gtk_with_its_own_aura_in_chrome/).

Comment: What is it? And what does it mean for a theme designer?

Comment: "What is it? And what does it mean for a theme designer?" Ask this as another question in the appropriate SE site.